# Conditional formatting of Calendar View for an Events List not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I'm having trouble colour coding a calendar view for my 'events' list in SharePoint.

I was able to colour code a standard SharePoint list's calendar view without issue (see below) but for some reason it's not working when trying to recreate the same list and view for my 'events' content type list.

[image]

As shown below, I'm not even able to set a global style for all items, let alone coding by my category column.

[image]

I did a search on Google and on here but I didn't see any forums that had this issue. Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you creating a list with classic "Calendar" list template & showing it in modern experience OR are you creating a blank/custom list and adding "Event" content type in the list?

Comment: Could you please provide more information in this thread, for example, the JSON code you are trying to color the list?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have this same problem. I created a List in SP and displayed it as a calendar with conditional formatting, no problem. But then I found out you can only connect classic Event Lists to Outlook so I recreated the calendar as an Events List using New View, and now conditional formatting rules don't change anything. Also, notice how the Title field is shown twice in the drop down for Conditional Formatting (I've tried rules with both, it makes no difference).

JSON code is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalEventClass": {
    "operator": ":",
    "operands": [
      {
        "operator": "==",
        "operands": [
          "[$Title]",
          "IRQR Time Slot"
        ]
      },
      "=if(@isSelected == true, 'sp-css-color-WhiteFont sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGreen' , 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-MintGreenFont')",
      ""
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/125546)